# localhost/phpmyadmin showing blank screen

Tags: phpmyadmin

In my local machine http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ is displaying the blank page.

I tried reinstalling XAMPP but no luck! I didn't find proper solution in Internet to resolve this issue.Was able to load http://localhost/xampp/ .

Any pointers on this issue. Appreciate your Suggestions!

Comment: Try open xampp control panel and click on "admin" nearby mySql, after having it running, obviously, and check if it works. If not, try to post your config file

Comment: this is not a solution to this specific issue but have you tried using another MySQL display-er rather than PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: @Nick - Thank you for Reply ! I tried opening xampp control panel and click on "admin" near mySql, but still blank page is displaying in http://localhost/phpmyadmin/.